# JSR 303 Bean validation using groups - intermittent incorrect error message

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I have come across some really weird behaviour when using the bean validation implementation supplied by 'org.apache.bval.bundle-1.1.1.jar'.

With the unit test below:

```
package testing;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.apache.bval.jsr.ApacheValidationProvider;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertFalse;

public class ValidationTestingTest {

  interface Marker {}

  class HasValidation {

    private List<String> holder = new LinkedList<String>();

    @SystemErrorInfo(errorNumber = 33)
    @AssertFalse(groups = Marker.class)
    public boolean isServiceAgreementCurrencyDifferentToBankAccount() {
      return false;
    }

    @SystemErrorInfo(errorNumber = 22)
    @AssertFalse(groups = Marker.class)
    public boolean isTooManyReconciliationTotalsFound() {
      boolean result = (holder.size() > 1);
      return result;
    }

    @SystemErrorInfo(errorNumber = 11)
    @AssertFalse(groups = Marker.class)
    public boolean isInsufficientAvailableFunds() {
      return false;
    }

    public List<String> getHolder() {
      return holder;
    }

    public void setHolder(List<String> holder) {
      this.holder = holder;
    }

    public void addToHolder(String s) {
      holder.add(s);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    HasValidation h = new HasValidation();
    h.addToHolder("ssss");
    h.addToHolder("ssss2");

    Validator beanValidator = getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<HasValidation>> violationSet = beanValidator.validate(h, Marker.class);

    for (ConstraintViolation<HasValidation> constraintViolation : violationSet) {
      System.out.println(constraintViolation);
    }

    assertEquals(1, violationSet.size());
    assertTrue(violationSet.iterator().next().getPropertyPath().toString().contains("tooManyReconciliationTotalsFound"));
  }

  private Validator getValidator() {
    Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byProvider(ApacheValidationProvider.class).configure();
    ValidatorFactory myfactory = configuration.buildValidatorFactory();
    Validator beanValidator = myfactory.getValidator();
    return beanValidator;
  }
}
```

If I repeatedly run it, occassionally the test will fail with the incorrect error message. I am pretty sure this is a bug in the implementation itself, rather than a fault in my code, however I am not overly familiar with the use of groups when performing the validation, so it could be as a result of that.
Does any one have any idea why the test fails intermittently, or is it likely a bug and so I should report it as such?

If I switch the provider to the Hibernate validator supplied by 'hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar' then the test passes every time.

Comment: Do you know the exact state of your values when it fails?

Comment: The output when the test is successful (from the sys out) is: `ConstraintViolationImpl{rootBean=testing.ValidationTestingTest$HasValidation@880ec60, propertyPath='tooManyReconciliationTotalsFound', message='must be false', leafBean=testing.ValidationTestingTest$HasValidation@880ec60, value=true}`

Comment: And when the test fails, it is: `ConstraintViolationImpl{rootBean=testing.ValidationTestingTest$HasValidation@880ec60, propertyPath='serviceAgreementCurrencyDifferentToBankAccount', message='must be false', leafBean=testing.ValidationTestingTest$HasValidation@880ec60, value=true}`

Comment: Jon, I am interested to know what are the elements inside holder and what is its size when it is successful and when it is unsuccessful. Also, I am interested to know the errornumber when it fails.

Comment: Ah I see. The elements inside `holder` remain unchanged. So stays as `ssss` and `ssss2`. Size of 2. How would I get access to the error number? The existing code I have - not shown here- uses the propertyPath and reflection to obtain it. But as the properyPath is incorrect, so is the error number.

Comment: You can debug, can't you?

Comment: I think based on your comments that I am going about it the right way and there is a possible issue with the framework? Is that fair to say?

Comment: Jon, why don't you debug or log the errors? The most important question in the current stage is what is the error. In this moment even this is unclear, so your task evidently is to find out what the error is.

Comment: It was more to validate I wasn't doing something really obviously stupid. I have gone through a few times on debug and can see the path through the code on the failure. But it never seems to be a 'success' path when I go through in debug. I think rather than debug, I will add logging to the framework code and do it that way. 
Thanks for the help and suggestions.